# ¿Los arreglos son basados en 0 o en 1 en Delphi/Pascal?

Tags: array, delphi, pascal

Quiero hacer un arreglo en Delphi. He encontrado una solución con este código:

```
var arr: array of String;
```

Cada vez que agrego algo, lo hago de esta forma:

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  var arr : array of String;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
  aux :string;
  len:integer;
begin
  len := Length(arr) + 1;
  SetLength(arr, len);
  arr[len-1] := 'abc' + IntToStr(len);
  Button1.Caption := arr[len-1]; // just to writeout something
end;
```

Soy un programador C++ y no se nada sobre Pascal. Siempre he escuchado que los índices en Pascal comienzan en 1 y no en 0. En el procedimiento de arriba, hago `arr[len-1]` como si el índice empezara en 0, y funciona!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En Delphi (o en Pascal en general), hay distintos tipos de arreglos, y la respuesta depende del tipo de arreglo en uso. En tu caso estás utilizando arreglos dinámicos:

## Arreglos dinámicos

**Indices basados en 0**

```
var
  a: array of Integer;
begin
  SetLength(a, 500);
  a[0] := 0;   //primer elemento 
  a[499] := 1; //último elemento
```

## Arreglos estáticos

Pueden tener **índices arbitrarios**

```
var
  i: Integer;
  b: array [50..100] of Integer;
  c: array[-10..10] of Integer; 
begin
  for i := 50 to 100 do b[i] := i * i;

  //Nota la declaración del índice que inicia en negativo
  for i := -10 to 10 do c[i] := i * i;
```

## Cadenas de caracteres

## Compilador tradicional (win32/win64)

**Los índices inician en 1**

```
var
  c: String;
begin
  c := 'Zap!';
  c[1] := 'W';
  ShowMessage(c); /// Muestra 'Wap!'
```

## Compilador NEXTGEN (Android, iOS, OSX, Linux)

**Los índices inician en 1**

```
var
  c: String;
begin
  c := 'Zap!';
  c[0] := 'W';
  ShowMessage(c); /// Muestra 'Wap!'
```

## Funciones auxiliares

Al trabajar con arreglos, en cualquier caso se puede utilizar las funciones [`Low()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Low) y [`High()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.High) para determinar los límites del índice de un arreglo.

```
var
  arr1: array[-10..20] of Integer;
  arr2: array of Integer;
  C: string;
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := Low(arr1) to High(arr1) do
    //algo
  for I := Low(arr2) to High(arr2) do
    //algo más
  for I := Low(C) to High(C) do
    //algo más aún
```

Delphi tiene además clases para manejar arreglos genéricos [`TArray<T>`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Generics.Collections.TArray) y otras [colecciones genéricas](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Generics.Collections) que te pueden ser de utilidad.